# String in fprintf is wrong datatype (%s)

Tags: c, arrays, string, char, printf

Im sure this question comes up quite often, but I have found no problem like this one whilest searching.
My Problem is, that I get a wrong datatype, when I use the function fprintf("%s", string[20]).
How can I get the right datatype?

Code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main() {

        FILE *CSV;
        int anz;
        char name[20];
        char gesch;
  CSV = fopen(argv[1], "r");
           while((fscanf(CSV,"%d,%s,%c\n", &anz,&name[20],&gesch)) != EOF )
           fprintf(stdout,"Anzahl:%d\tName:%s\tGeschlecht:%c\n", anz, name[20], gesch);
           return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Error:

> help.c: In function ‘main’: help.c:24:8: warning: format ‘%s’ expects
>   argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 4 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
>           fprintf(stdout,"Anzahl:%d\tName:%s\tGeschlecht:%c\n", anz, name[20], gesch);

Comment: `&name[20]` is a pointer *beyond* name. you probably want just `name` , or `&name[0]` which is the same. (you are also not checking the size; the input string could be larger than 19 characters)

Comment: try `fscanf(CSV,"%d,%19[^,],%c\n", &anz, name, &gesch)` and `fprintf(stdout,"Anzahl:%d\tName:%s\tGeschlecht:%c\n", anz, name, gesch)`

Comment: will "name" or "&name[0]" print the whole string?

Comment: @asdasdasd1234 Yes.

Answer (score 4):

You have two, or possibly three, problems.

The first regarding the warning for the `printf` Call is because you use `name[20]` as the argument for `"%s"`. This is the *single character* at element 21 in the array. Besides being out of bounds, the single character gets converted to an `int` which leads to the warning message. It will not work either, because the `printf` function will treat this unknown character (remember it's outside of the array) as an address, a pointer, to the string to print, and since it most likely will not be anything valid at the address pointed to by that character, you might get very weird output. It is, in fact, *undefined behavior*.

The second problem has to do with your `fscanf` call. The [`scanf` family of functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) expect to get a pointer to the first element in the array you provide. To get a pointer to the *first* element, either use `&name[0]` or just plain `name` (arrays naturally decays to pointers to their first element).

The expression `&name[20]` results in a pointer to element number 21, which is beyond the end of the array. When `fscanf` writes using this pointer it will write out of bounds, and you will have *undefined behavior*.

---

There is also a possible third problem, depending on the input from the file. If the comma after the name is not separated from the name with a space, the `"%s"` format will read that as part of the name. The `"%s"` format for `scanf` separates on white-space (e.g. space, tab, newline), not on the arbitrary separator you provide in the format string.

To solve that problem you must use the kind of obscure `"%["` format, which tell `scanf` to read a set of characters. In this case you want to tell `scanf` to read everything *but* the comma, which will lead to the format to be `"%[^,],"`. The `^` character means that the character set is negated, and that everything but the provided set is read. The trailing comma is to actually read (and skip) the comma after the string, because `"%[^,]"` will only read up to but not including the comma.

You should also safe-guard for `scanf` to write beyond the bounds of the array you provide, and you do that by telling `scanf` the width of the array like `"%19[^,],"`. This format will write at most 19 characters, plus the terminating zero, to the array.

You should also check for possible format errors when reading the file, and you do that by checking how many of the provided formats the `fscanf` function was able to read and parse. This is checked by comparing the return value of the `fscanf` function with the number of formats, which is three in your case.

And lastly you don't need the trailing `"\n"` in the `fscanf` format string. In fact it might even be causing your program to "hang", if the input file is not terminated by a space *and* some other non-space character. It will work alright anyway, because just about all formats, including `"%d"` will skip leading white-space, like the newline left over from the previous call to `fscanf`.

To put all of this together, your loop might instead look like

```
while (fscanf(CSV, "%d,%19[^,],%c\n", &anz, name, &gesch) == 3)
    printf("Anzahl:%d\tName:%s\tGeschlecht:%c\n", anz, name, gesch);
```